# Make a reusable modal component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Following this [tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-reusable-modal-component-in-angular-9-using-ng-bootstrap-50c0aa5f3a65) I've created a reusable and customizable modal component. However, I have one problem.
Imagine there are 2 components, A and B, and in both I open a modal using the modal component. For component A, when a user clicks on submit button, functionA() of component A must be executed, and for B, functionB() of component B. How can I enable the modal .ts file to have access and execute both functionA() and functionB()?

If possible, I don't want to have a global service file, where all functions are there, or move all related functions to modal.ts file, rather, I like to keep each individual component clean and separate but optimize the interaction between them, such that I only pass the name of the function and the required input arguments. Does any one know  what is the best practice to achieve this? Thank you in advance.

.ts of the modal:

```
  open(): Promise<boolean> {
     ...
  }

  async close(): Promise<void> {
      const result = await this.modalConfig.onClose();
      this.modalRef.close(result);  
  }

  async dismiss(): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }
}
```

config.ts of the modal:

```
export class ModalConfig {
  modalTitle: string;
  data: string = '';
  onClose?(): Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

.html of the modal:

```
<ng-template #modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" (click)="dismiss()">cancel</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="close()">Ok</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move dismiss() and close() method in a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-09) and call them from there. This should solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you @oscar, inspired by your solution, I’ve splitted the modal .html, so that the dismiss button is shown and handled in the modal component but the close button is rendered and handled in other components. This way I am able to reuse the modal component while components are kept separately.

Answer (score 2):

I made this simple working version for you to understand a reusable modal component, please go through the code and let me know if any issues, we can code the modal once and reuse it throughout the entire application easily!

modal component

html

```
<div
  class="modal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  *ngIf="open"
  style="display:block;"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">{{ config.title }}</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
          (click)="discardWrapper($event)"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{ config.description }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          (click)="saveWrapper($event)"
        >
          Save changes
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-secondary"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          (click)="discardWrapper($event)"
        >
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from './modal.service';

export class ModalConfig {
  title?: string = '';
  description?: string = '';
  save?: Function = () => {};
  discard?: Function = () => {};

  constructor(
    title: string = '',
    description: string = '',
    save = null,
    discard = null
  ) {
    if (title) this.title = title;
    if (description) this.description = description;
    if (save) this.save = save;
    if (discard) this.discard = discard;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

  get open() {
    return this.modalService.isOpen;
  }

  get config() {
    return this.modalService.config;
  }

  discardWrapper(event: Event) {
    this.modalService.isOpen = false;
    if (this.config.discard) {
      this.config.discard(event);
    }
  }

  saveWrapper(event: Event) {
    this.modalService.isOpen = false;
    if (this.config.save) {
      this.config.save(event);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalConfig } from './modal.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ModalService {
  isOpen = false;
  config = new ModalConfig();

  constructor() {}

  open(config: ModalConfig) {
    this.config = { ...this.config, ...config };
    this.isOpen = true;
  }
}
```

A component using this logic

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalService } from '../modal/modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  openModal() {
    this.modalService.open({
      title: 'test',
      description: 'test description',
    });
  }
}
```

html

```
<p>a works!</p>

<button (click)="openModal()" class="btn btn-primary">open modal</button>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-h6gj3p?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.component.ts,src%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.service.ts,src%2Fmodal%2Fmodal.component.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fa%2Fa.component.ts,src%2Fa%2Fa.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts,src%2Fb%2Fb.component.html&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is in main.ts? The name of component a is course-list. When I add it as `<app-course-list></app-course-list>` I get:` <app-course-list> is not a known element`, however, I have imported it.

Comment: @user6781 check the selector of component a if its `course-list` or `app-course-list`. The same should be used to import it!

Comment: I tried, didn't work, something is missing in my code that I can't integrate your code. But will work on it.

Comment: @user6781 all the best, hope you fix it :)